# Use differents configs in CKEDITOR with Django

Tags: django, ckeditor

In my Django back end, I have a full toolbar.
However, I want to propose Ckeditor to my users with a minimum of functionnalities.

The problem is, I don't know how to this.
I tried to override my config :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'default',
      {
         toolbar : 'Basic',
      });
</script>
```

But nothing happened, even after removing my browser cache.

This is my Django settings :

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"


CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'height': 500,
        'width': 1500,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not working because in your Django code the settings "CKEDITOR_CONFIGS" for toolbar defined as full.

Also, you can configure toolbar through online builder - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_plugins.html.

Comment: I tried many things, but nothing worked. I finally decide to work with a secure home made textarea.